# Replace this if-then-else statement by a single method invocation

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I wanted to execute func2 with 2nd parameter as true only when value of bool1 is false and func2 with 2nd parameter as false will be called every time but for some reason Sonar is taking it as non complaint code even though i am not even using any else statement neither returning anything from the function.

```
func1(Obj1, bool1){
    if(!bool1){
        func2(obj1,true);
    }
    func2(obj1,false);  // Note this is called UNCONDITIONALLY
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue without duplicating code of func2.Most of the other answers in stack overflow are talking about returning something based on some condition but in this i am supposed to execute func2 even though if condition is true.

Comment: `func2(obj1, !bool1)`.

Comment: @user229044 Well maybe... There's no `else` in the code as given, but it's also syntactically broken, so hard to know if the lack of `else` is a transcription error.

Comment: @user16320675, that is what i have mentioned if bool1 is false then expression becomes true and func1 will get executed.

Comment: I am sorry, got it now. Corrected it.

Comment: now it makes sense, maybe Sonar also got confused...and I do not think it is a duplicate of the actual linked to question

Comment: Any idea how it can be resolved, Only way i can think of is to separate logic of func2 into two different function which includes duplicating lots of code.

Comment: I would report it to Sonar as a bug.

Comment: I've reproduced it using SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ IDEA, and reported it at https://community.sonarsource.com/t/false-positive-for-an-if-without-else/81463

Comment: As a workaround i enclosed the method with false argument into another method with a different name and Sonar issue goes away.